# Retrieve IDXGISurface from ID2D1BitmapBrush

Tags: directx, direct2d

My application uses 2 DXGISurfaceRenderTargets.

The 1st render target is used to create `ID2D1Bitmap`, then `ID2D1BitmapBrush` from it.

Resulting `ID2D1BitmapBrush` is used to FillGeometry on the 2nd render target.

Is it possible to retrieve `IDXGISurface` that was used to create `ID2D1BitmapBrush` from the `ID2D1BitmapBrush` or the `ID2D1Bitmap`?

Windows 8 has `ID2D1Bitmap1` with `GetSurface` method, but I need this on Windows 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot, as you pointed out, only ID2D1Bitmap1 can retrieve the surface by calling Getsurface, and that's only works on Windows 8.

If you want to use the surface, can you store it after creation, and then pass it as the parameter to the function which used it?

[D2D1Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[D2D1Bitmap1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)